# Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}}$ converges or diverges?

The $\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}} \le \frac{1}{k}$ is a zero sequence, so the series has a chance to converge. None of the criterion of convergence I know seems to work directly in this case.

Comment: This seems a nice series for the k-th root test

Comment: @BernardMassé not really, this criterion does not work in this case.

Comment: You're right. I spoke too fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one knows that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(1+\frac1k \right)^k=e
$$ then, as $k \to \infty$, one has
$$
\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}}= \frac{1}{(k+1) \cdot \left(1+\frac1k \right)^k }\sim \frac{e^{-1}}{k+1}
$$ and the given series *diverges* by the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).